# Laravel 5.4 - Timezone configuration

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to change the value of `timezone` of Laravel's `config\app.php` so it'll be the same on what's the time on my computer?

Right now, it is set to Asia/Manila.

`'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila',`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a timezone supported by PHP. An overview about available timezones can be find here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Set your timezone in `app/config/app.php`   same as your timezone and the time should be the same as in your pc. After you change the timezone don't forget `php artisan config:cache.`

For Sweden i.e. you set timezone to `"Europe/Stockholm"`

dynamically changing the date :

Go ahead and create a Service Provider, or use the AppServiceProvider, and set the config value in there.

```
//lets say you want to set timezone based on $timestamp
    $timestamp = '2017-02-06 14:34:00';
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Stockholm');
    $date->setTimezone('UTC');

    Config::set('app.timezone', $date);
```

Comment: I want it to be able to change it dynamically without changing the `timezone`'s value but by changing my computer's time.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach it is store everything in the database as UTC always. Never ever change this on the server side. Then when someone logs in I use momentjs with momentjs-timezone to guess what the client side timezone is and add it to a hidden field on the login page. It stores the timezone in the user's session.

Then you don't modify the way you store the datetime, to only modify the way you display it. So this is what a lot of my blade templates look like:

```
{{ $model->created_at->timezone(Session::get('timezone'))->format('M j, Y g:ia') }}
```

That way every time someone logs in it should show times based off of what their computer is currently set to.

```
<input type="hidden" name="timezone" id="timezone" value="" />
<script>
    document.getElementById('timezone').value = moment.tz.guess();
</script>
```

Comment: "Never ever change this on the server side." Do you mean I should always use UTC? What would happen if it's on a place's timezone, for example in my case. I've been using `Asia/Manila` since the start.

Comment: Then I would convert the times in the database. That is the whole point of always using UTC no matter what. You don't have to worry about knowing which timezone was set. Otherwise you will need to store not only a datetime with just `Y-m-d H:i:s` you will also need to store the UTC offset.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

1. Get client time zone using moment-timezone.js
   if you are using API call using ajx then set the header
   headers: { 'X-TimeZone': moment.tz.guess() }
2. for back-end use laravel middle ware in my case I used

> ```
> app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php
>  
>
> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
> {
>
>     if(!empty(request()->header('X-TimeZone'))){
>         date_default_timezone_set(request()->header('X-TimeZone'));
>     }
>     return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
>     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
>     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-TimeZone, X-Request-With')
>     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
> }
> ```

No need any fancy setting it will work as a charm
If it works for you don't forgot to give thumbs up